# Mysql: How can i know whether my mysql binary has ssl support or not

Tags: mysql, security, ssl

I am trying to secure my db servers secured on the live setup. I have read it like we can enable ssl in mysql to make the data transfer over the network between master and slave to be encrypted.

Shall someone help on how can i know whether i have the ssl support or not. If i have how can i enable this as i cant compile a binary again with --have-ssl

Thanks in advance. 
Regards,
UDAY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try starting MySQL with `--ssl` option:

```
mysqld --ssl --help
```

If the server does not support SSL, you'll see an error:

```
[ERROR] mysqld: unknown option '--ssl'
```

On running server, you can check `have_ssl` or `have_openssl` variables:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_ssl';
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_openssl';
```

Comment: Ya..... I have just seen from the mannual even. Thank you so much for the quick reply. But I hard saw the companies using or enabling this ssl. Is it that useless or it will have some performance issues as it would need to encrypt and decrypt for every connection...?

Comment: There certainly will be some performance penalty involved with SSL use, that's the main reason why they disabled it by default. It's impossible to say how much it would affect things in your case and whether increased security would worth it. You should consider doing your own benchmarking if you're concerned about performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @BluesRockAddict answer, *on a running server* you can also do the following...

**View the paths to your SSL Certificates and Keys..**

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'SSL%';
```

This will show you the path to the SSL certs and keys that your MySql connection should use. These paths are required in order for the `have_ssl` and `have_openssl` to be `ENABLED`, assuming openssl is installed.

*Example*

[image: View SSL paths.]

If the ssl paths are empty then you will need to create the required certificates and restart your MySql service. This site has a pretty good explanation on how to do this, [How to enable SSL for MySQL server and client](http://xmodulo.com/enable-ssl-mysql-server-client.html). Once you do that the `have_ssl` and `have_openssl` should appear `ENABLED`.

**Check to see if SSL is in use..**

```
mysql> \s
```

Look for the this line...

```
SSL:         Not in use
```

*Example*

[image: View if SSL is in use.]